# Error running sample Microsoft UCMA 4.0 sample in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, ucma

I just want to test prebuilt Microsoft UCMA 4.0 Quickstart sample Application from Visual Studio 2013.

If i press Start, I get the warning:

```
Warning 1   The primary reference "Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the assembly "System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" which was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". RecorderSample
```

and a bunch of errors, for example:

```
Error   3   The type or namespace name 'AudioVideo' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  C:\Program Files\Microsoft UCMA 4.0\SDK\Core\Sample Applications\QuickStarts\AudioVideoCall\Recorder\RecorderSample.cs  10  35  RecorderSample
```

I have .net framework 4.5.1 on my pc

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by going to project, project properties, application, target framework and changing to 4.5.1